# Excel: Compare two columns on two workbooks and if match copy to a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I was hoping to get some help with filtering data out from two separate workbooks (WB1 and WB2). I would like to compare data from two columns between two workbooks and if the data matches then I copy both column items to a new workbook (WB3).

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J4jc.png)

Thus copied items on WB3 are only when col1 and col2 matches between WB1 and WB2.

Comment: S.O. isn't a distributor of code ready to use, what do you have tried to do what do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To encourage actually trying to solve the problem by yourself, I'll limit myself to showing a sample code which you should be able to adapt to your needs. The method might not be perfect in terms of performance, but it's 100% reliable (I hope) as long as you want to match unique, not repetetive values.

You'll want to create a For loop where a variable holds the value from WB1, and nest another For loop that will compare the variable to cells in WB2.

```
Sub CopyBetweenWorksheets()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long, k As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, myVar As Double
Set ws1 = Workbooks("First workbook").Worksheets("Sheet 1")
Set ws1 = Workbooks("Second workbook").Worksheets("Sheet 1")
'obviously just examples

For i = 2 To 150    'example last row of ws1

myVar = ws1.Cells(i, 1)

    For k = 2 To 320 'example last row of ws2
        If ws2.Cells(k, 1) = myVar Then
            'your commands what to copy go here
            Exit For    'this is an important line that speeds it up a lot
        End If
    Next k
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot, this got me going. The command I have added is it counts the number of rows for each sheet and use that as a For loop basis. I then copy the rows that match. My only question is I am getting to a loop number of 700 for k and getting a sub error 9. Any ideas why that ould happen?

Comment: Just a quick question. I have now got myself into excel crashing as the loop i goes all the way to 200,000. How do I stop excel from crashing everytime I run the script?

Comment: There's plenty of answers for "Subscript out of range" here. Maybe the content of one of the cells doesn't match the variable type.
As for the crash - copying whole row takes up far more resources than writing values in cells. You may try that.